# What is \f@size and how can I convert the value between units?

Tags: fontsize, fontspec

What is `\f@size`?

Why doesn't `\convertto{\f@size bp}{pt}` work?

Microsoft Word uses big points to measure fonts according to a comment to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274609/13552

I went about converting the points to big points in the most logical way I could think of, using `\convertto{bp}{1pt}` to convert 1pt into bp.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse} % For \NewDocumentCommand (LaTeX3)
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\thefontsizePoint{m}{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\hfill{\string#1}}\par}
\NewDocumentCommand\thefontsizeBigPoint{m}{{#1 The current font size is: \convertto{bp}{\f@size pt} bp\hfill{\string#1}}\par}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\fontsizes}{m}{%
    \begingroup
    #1
    \offinterlineskip
    \setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\tiny
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\scriptsize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\footnotesize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\small
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\normalsize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\large
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\Large
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\LARGE
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\huge
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\Huge
    \endgroup
    \begingroup
    \offinterlineskip
    \setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\tiny
    \thefontsizePoint\scriptsize
    \thefontsizePoint\footnotesize
    \thefontsizePoint\small
    \thefontsizePoint\normalsize
    \thefontsizePoint\large
    \thefontsizePoint\Large
    \thefontsizePoint\LARGE
    \thefontsizePoint\huge
    \thefontsizePoint\Huge
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}
\fontsizes{}
\end{document}
```

## Related Questions

- [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc)
- [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm)
- [Globally redefining 1 pt to 1/72 in (PostScript point) and other similar changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/globally-redefining-1-pt-to-1-72-in-postscript-point-and-other-similar-changes)

## Updated Code that David Carlisle's Answer Implies

Hopefully this is correct:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse} % For \NewDocumentCommand (LaTeX3)
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\thefontsizeBigPoint{m}{{#1 Current font size: \f@size\ pt (1/72.27 in)\hfill{\string#1}}\par}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\thefontsizePoint{m}{{#1 Current~font~size:~\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \f@size bp }{ 1 pt }~bp~(1/72~in)\hfill{\string#1}}\par}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\fontsizes}{m}{%
\textbf{\TeX\ Point}

(1 pt in TeX) equals 1/72.27 in (= 2540/7227 mm ≈ 0.35145980351 mm) % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/globally-redefining-1-pt-to-1-72-in-postscript-point-and-other-similar-changes
\bigskip

    \begingroup
    #1
    \offinterlineskip
    \setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\tiny
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\scriptsize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\footnotesize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\small
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\normalsize
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\large
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\Large
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\LARGE
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\huge
    \thefontsizeBigPoint\Huge
    \endgroup

\bigskip\textbf{PostScript Point}

(1 bp in TeX) equals 1/72 in (= 127/360 mm = 0.352(7) mm). It is commonly used unit in DTP nowadays. % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/globally-redefining-1-pt-to-1-72-in-postscript-point-and-other-similar-changes
\bigskip

    \begingroup
    \offinterlineskip
    \setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}
    \thefontsizePoint\tiny
    \thefontsizePoint\scriptsize
    \thefontsizePoint\footnotesize
    \thefontsizePoint\small
    \thefontsizePoint\normalsize
    \thefontsizePoint\large
    \thefontsizePoint\Large
    \thefontsizePoint\LARGE
    \thefontsizePoint\huge
    \thefontsizePoint\Huge
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fontsizes{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See `source2e` for `\f@size` ;-)

Comment: Running your example `xelatex` complains about `\convertto` itself. Where is `\convertto` from?

Comment: The comment that you reference doesn't say that TeX uses bp to measure fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Excuse me, my mistake. I had it backwards. Leave it to Microsoft Word to be the weird one and use "big points".

Comment: @macmadness86 Microsoft word, PostScript, PDF, CSS, SVG all use the same (PostScript) definition of the "point" unit. TeX is the only one that uses the definition that TeX uses (although it is numerically closer to the traditional printers point)

Comment: Since 72/72.27 = 0.99626 (approximately), if you want in Word what would be a 10pt font in TeX, just ask for 9.9626 (bp). It's just as simple as a conversion factor. Even if I were a Word user, I wouldn't bother about the difference.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I fixed the code to include `\convertto`. It is from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm

Comment: @egreg — do you mean *especially* if you were a Word user, you wouldn't bother about the difference? :)

Comment: @WillRobertson In Italian grammar we have “periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà” for describing a case of conditional clause like this one. `;-)` What I meant is that the difference is about 0.4% and the control I can get with a word processor is much worse with respect to TeX. So, why bother? Yes, I know: a secretary might look in the PDF file and see 9.96 points, and argue that the font is not at ten point. The objection of course is that *it is at ten typographer's points* and the rules didn't specify which point to use.

Comment: @egreg I am more concerned with the fact that my font sizes may be not in agreement with corporate design (which deals with fonts and sizes). As you noted before, the difference is minimal and perhaps unnoticeable, therefore irrelevant. Still, it is nice to have the ability to provide quick visual inspection for those unbelievers. My eye does not see the difference, actually. One of the things I love about LaTeX is its precision. :)

Comment: @macmadness86 for that use you don't need conversion just use `bp` when setting up your class.

Comment: a more insidious cause of "inequality" is not printing out a pdf file "actual size" instead of "fit to page".

Comment: @barbarabeeton So true Barbara. This was really important when I created a perfectly-sized PDF for a Canon Type J Tray for DVD labels such that I did not need to use any special (annoying) software  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223851/13552

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\show` will stop tex (as if for an error message) and show the meaning of any command.

```
\makeatletter
\show\f@size
```

Produces

```
*\show\f@size
> \f@size=macro:
->10.
```

`\f@size` is the current nominal font size, in `pt` (not `bp`).

The posted code produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\thefontsizePoint ...ent font size is: \convertto
```

and you give no indication of its intended behaviour, so hard to comment on that.

---

Since you are using expl3 anyway you can use its functions to convert between units eg

```
\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { 1bp } { 1mm }
```

will show 1bp in mm

see `texdoc interface3` page 85

Comment: Sorry about the `\convertto` macro. I forgot to include it in my code. I fixed that. The `expl3` way works: see updated question. Just out of curiousity, how would I do it in LaTeX2e? I suppose with `\convertto`.

Comment: @macmadness86 I probably wouldn't use that macro, just multiply by  0.99626